# Add Submenu in sidebar on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sidebar, submenu

i would like to show the submenu of my page in a custom page template on the left side in a Sidebar-area. Does any know the code for showing the submenu. 
I'm using `Wordpress 3.4.1`.

Answer (score 0):

**Register Menus**

Firstly, in your theme's functions.php, you need to write a function to register the names of your menus.

```
    function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array( 'sidebar-menu' => __( 'Sidebar Menu' ) )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

**Display Menus on Theme**

Once you've done that, your theme will be almost ready. The last preparation step is to tell the theme where you want the menus to show up.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'sidebar-menu' ) ); ?>
```

That's all the background work. To finish, you would simply visit the Appearance -> Menus panel in your site admin.

Please read the wordpress codex site.. it has plenty of information on how to do this..

http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus